# Will the games I play with WINE be able to use the graphic drivers I install on Ubuntu?

Tags: ati, wine

I installed WINE and I'll play Company of Heroes on it. But I'm not sure how the graphics will be. So hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have graphics driver installed wine will not be able to make use of accelerated graphics on the system, but that's true for everything else on the system.

Running games in wine might not always be perfect some games have high compatibility with wine some have lower or don't work at all.

Check for game compatibility here:
https://appdb.winehq.org/

So yes you will need graphics drivers.

Comment: There is also a native linux version of company of heroes 2 on steam.

Comment: Hey there. Thank you for your answer. I asked it based on CoH but of course I also wondered it for other games too. I actually wanted to ask this: Should the installed graphical drivers be Ubuntu's or (via WINE) Windows'?

Comment: It varies by game. IMO if you want to play Windows games it is best to dual boot. Some can be played on wine or steam or playonlinux, but many takes manual configuration and many have minor or not so minor bugs.